# Show next and previous images from array and show using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Assume array of images is given as input , build a functionality of next and previous button. When next button is clicked some random images from the array will be displayed, when previous button is clicking you should open the previous image history one by one.

Given :

```
images = [img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7]
```

On clicking next , pick some random like = img1, img4, img7, img2 ...
On clicking Previous , go in history reverse order = img2,img7,img4,img1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On clicking next, push each image to a second array; on clicking prev, pick an image from the second array (in consecutive order) and show it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
var images = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7'];
var randomImages = [];

var open = function(image){
    //opening logic here     
};

var onNextClick = function(){
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)];
    randomImages.push(image);
    open(image);
};

var onPreviousClick = function(){
    var image = randomImages.pop();
    if(image){
        open(image);
    } else{
        alert('No previous image');
    }
};
```

Attach the onNextClick handler to a 'Next' button's click event, and the onPreviousClick handler to a 'Previous' button's click event.